# Python 3.8: for loop goes infinite

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, infinite-loop

I have a list with strings as elements. All of them are in lower case. I want to modify the list so that this list also contains the strings in upper case for the first letter.
I wrote this for loop:

```
> words = ["when", "do", "some", "any"]     
with_title_words = words
> 
>     for u in words:
>         u.title()
>         with_title_words.append(u)
>     print(with_title_words)
```

When I execute it goes infinite. It outputs all the string elements starting with the capital letter.

Comment: You have an infinite loop because you continuously add elements to the loop you're consuming from. `with_title_words = words` does not do a deep copy. It's like a reference.

Comment: Also, see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list/2612990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = ["when", "do", "some", "any"]
with_title_words = words[:]

for word in words:
    with_title_words.append(word.title())

print(with_title_words)
```

Outputs:

```
['when', 'do', 'some', 'any', 'When', 'Do', 'Some', 'Any']
```

or create an empty list `word_title_words = []` to add only the titled strings.

Comment: What does the semicolon mean in word[:]? Never saw that before

Comment: Slice notation.  In this example [:] copies the list rather than references it.